# Vim finds incorrect matching bracket when using %

Tags: vim

I am trying to learn VIM, buy I noticed when I try using the % command to go to a matching bracket, VIM  sometimes finds the correct matching bracket and is sometimes way off. Has anyone ever come across this with a solution?

Comment: Post some example text that illustrates the failure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because:

1. You have an actual syntax error with a mismatched paren or curly brace somewhere.
2. You have a value in `cpoptions` that prevents semi-intelligent brace matching. Look up `:help cpoptions` and `:help %`.
3. You have something too sophisicated for plain old Vim matching to handle. Try installing the `matchit` plugin, which may help. Common culprits are braces inside comments or regexes.

Comment: there is a 4th non-obvious option: I had a "syntax error" in a comment.

Comment: Comments were meant to be included in #3. I should have been more explicit, because braces in comments is a common scenario that I had in mind when I wrote #3.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, vim parses brackets even in comments, which was happening in my case, I had a non-complete bracket pair commented out, meaning vim did not find bracket pairs correctly but the compiler had no problem, hence my confusion.

Comment: Yeah, comments and regexes are the usual culprits when I have this problem. This was meant to be implied by #3 in my list.

Answer (score 2):

`matchit` plugin would have saved me hours of frustration if I had found it earlier.

There's a small chance pasting this ugly command into your terminal will correctly set up the plugin:

`wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=8196; unzip download_script.php?src_id=8196; echo >> ~/.vimrc; echo -ne "source " >> ~/.vimrc; pwd | tr -d '\n' >> ~/.vimrc; echo -ne "/plugin/matchit.vim" >> ~/.vimrc; rm download_script.php\?src_id\=8196`

Then re-source your vimrc:

`:source ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Works perfectly for me (and its 2015 now)

Answer (score 0):

No, I haven't. It might indicate you have missing brackets.